# how to uninstall java-jdk after installing it using anaconda

Tags: python, conda

I have installed Java through anaconda:

```
conda install -c bioconda java-jdk
```

how to uninstall it again. I tried `pip unintall java`; `pip uninstall java-jdk`, `conda uninstall java` and `conda uninstall java-jdk` and nothing worked out.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Which SO are you using?

Comment: @HenriqueBranco, I am using windows 10

Comment: In my opinion, the best way is to download it through [this link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) and install

Comment: Or, if you still want to use the command line to do it, here is [anoter link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html) that may be helpful.

Comment: How can I make sure that the one I installed through Anaconda won't have any effect to using Java?

Comment: Try to uninstall it using the Windows uninstaller. That's completely possible and you avoid having possible future problems with Java, as your said.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Try running first

`conda list`

to see the name of the packages you want to remove

then you can use

`conda remove <package_name>`

you can also try adding `--force` but it can cause some issues in the
environment.. so should be used with caution